# Bulk Google Traffic Queries

Tags: bulk, traffic, transit

I am a Business Analyst. So this is a question asking if something can be done.

I am working with developers on a project. We are using Google Traffic. Our problem is:

- We have a trip with (lets say 9 stops).
- Each stop has a different known dwell time.
- We'd like to get the total time for the trip. Adding (travel 1) to (stop 1) to (travel 2) to (stop 2) to (travel 3)...

Because the durations between each stop might affect travel times depending on the time of day, currently our solution is:

- To make a call from start to stop 1, we get a fifteen minute travel time. (12:00 - 12:15)
- We then add the stop time (33 minutes)
- Then make call two starting from stop 1 to stop 2. 7 minute travel (12:48 - 12:55)
- We then add the stop time (21 minutes)
- Then make call three starting from stop 2 to stop 3. 10 minute travel (1:15 - 1:25)...

**The issue is that we have to make 9 separate calls for this trip.**

We would like to make a single call with all 9 stops and stop durations at once. 
Then have google send us back the total trip (transit + stop time 1 + transit time 2 + stop time 2 + transit time 3...). 
We don't want all the transit times without the consideration of the stop duration inbetween.

Our developers are saying the above bulk scenario can't be done using Google. That we have to make 9 separate calls. Is this true?